# Creating a slideshow with Jquery in Rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, slideshow

I have been looking all over to find a working example of making a slideshow with rails 3 using Jquery but I am not able to find a solution.

Is there a plugin which we could use for the slideshow if not can anyone direct me how I can make one with rails 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When I posted this question I was more interested in knowing how to integrate a Jquery slideshow with rails-3.

Have implemented it now by looking at various example on net. Here is the solution on github if anyone is looking for a similar kind of solution.

https://github.com/Akram-Khan/Slideshow

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I used for the same purpose "jQuery Cycle Plugin" - http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/.

Great flexibility, simple implementation and a lot of tutorials make this tool really useful.